# Why replace() in python3 doesn't work for long string

Tags: python-3.5

I have a task, to get raw text from HTML page. After HTML parsing, I receive a string with a lot '\n' symbols. When I'm trying to replace it with empty, replace function doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://shakespeare.mit.edu/lear/full.html') as response:
lear_bytes = response.read()
lear_html = str(lear_bytes)
soup = BeautifulSoup(lear_html, 'html.parser')
lear_txt_dirty = soup.get_text()
lear_txt_clean = str.replace(lear_txt_dirty, '\n', '')
print(lear_txt_clean)
```

Comment: can you create a [mcve] ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre after fixing an indent error, this code runs and demonstrates the problem... or not... its not really a problem!

Comment: @tdelaney so Python replace function works? Pheew I'm soooo relieved.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah, I was about to switch to `go` but what a relief!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sorting out string problems, its useful to print the `repr` of the string, so you can see what's really there. Replacing your print with:

```
#print(lear_txt_clean)
print("Num newlines", lear_txt_clean.count('\n'))
print(repr(lear_txt_clean[:80]))
```

I get

```
Num newlines 0
"b'\\n \\n \\n King Lear: Entire Play\\n \\n \\n \\n \\n \\n\\n\\nKing Lear\\n\\n      Shakesp"
```

You are processing a python byte representation of the text, not the real text. In your code, `lear_bytes` is a `bytes` object but `lear_html = str(lear_bytes)` doesn't decode the object, it gives you a python representation of the `bytes` object. Instead, you should just let `BeautifulSoup` have the raw bytes and let it sort it out:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://shakespeare.mit.edu/lear/full.html') as response:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), 'html.parser')
lear_txt_dirty = soup.get_text()
lear_txt_clean = str.replace(lear_txt_dirty, '\n', '')
print(lear_txt_clean[:80])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's work! Also, I'm realize that it possible to get the same result, by using decode method not the str, on lear_bytes.